# Refunded receipt JSON example

Tags: ios, app-store, subscription, receipt-validation, auto-renewable

I'm developing a web service and SDK for iOS for tracking auto-renewable subscriptions, and now developing a case where customer has refunded auto-renewable subscription.

Can anybody share any **iOS receipt example with refund** in JSON please? Receipt should have `cancellation_date` inside.

I have read documentation a lot, but it's not clear about `cancellation_reason` field, where is it located, inside `latest_receipt_info` or inside `pending_renewal_info` ?

Also would like to ask if someone knows, can Apple Care refund multiple transactions for auto-renewable subscription? i.e. subscription has been charged twice, will Apple Care refund two transactions or just last one?

I have posted the same question in Apple Developer Forums, but still got no reply: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119921

Comment: See: https://www.programmersought.com/article/28505107529/